# Using .detach() with multiple ajax elements on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, detach

I'm loading content from a database into a page with jQuery ajax. I have multiple divs of content, but would only like to view one div at a time.

I've managed to successfully detach the elements from the dom, but I can not figure out how to manage multiple divs so that only 1 div shows at a time (while the others remain detached).

Below is my code, here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XkzUK/

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul id="site-nav">
<li class="nav1"><a href="#recent">Recent</a></li>
<li class="nav2"><a href="#highlights">Highlights</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="content-listing">

<div id="recent">
<ul class="top-level">
</ul>
</div><!--end recent-->

<div id="highlights">
<ul class="top-level">
</ul>
</div><!--end highlights-->

</div><!--end content-listing-->​
```

JS:

```
var test; var test2
     //Recent $("#site-nav .nav1").on("click", function (event) {
    $("#site-nav li a").parents().removeClass("nav-active");
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
    if(typeof test === 'undefined') {
        test = $("#recent ul.top-level").load('/echo/html/', { html: '<li>1</li> <li>2</li> <li>3</li>' }, function () {
            //$(this).show().siblings().detach();
            alert("I'm new");
        });
    } else {
        test.appendTo("#content-listing");
        alert("I'm old");
    }
    event.preventDefault(); });

//Highlights $("#site-nav .nav2").on("click", function(event) {
    //test = $("#recent").detach();
    $("#site-nav li a").parents().removeClass("nav-active");
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
    if(typeof test2 === 'undefined') {
        test2 = $("#highlights ul.top-level").load('/echo/html/', { html: '<li>Apples</li> <li>Oranges</li> <li>Pears</li>' }, function () {
            //$(this).show().siblings().detach();
            alert("I'm new");
        });
    } else {
        test2.appendTo("#content-listing");
        alert("I'm old");
    }
    event.preventDefault(); });​
```

CSS:

```
.nav-active,.nav-active a{background-color:#fff;color:#e84182 !important;outline:none;}
.sub-active,.sub-active a{background-color:#fff;color:#e84182 !important;border:dotted 1px pink;border-width:1px 0 ;margin:-1px 0;outline:none;/*background:url(/assets/img/icon-branch.png) 2% 5px no-repeat #fff;*/}

#content-listing{background-color:#ea528d;}/*230px*/
#content-listing ul.top-level ul li{margin-left:5.882352941176%}
#content-listing li a{font-size:.8125em;line-height:1em;text-decoration:none;padding:2px 0;display:block;text-indent:2.678571428571%;outline:none;}
.visited{color:#ccc;}

#content-listing ul{z-index:4;position:relative;}/*230px*/
#content-listing ul.top-level{margin-top:5.3125em/*85px*/;}
#content-listing ul.top-level ul li{margin-left:6.521739130435%;}
#content-listing{width:29.113924050633%;float:left;padding-bottom:20010px;margin-bottom: -20000px;}
#content-listing li a{text-indent:6.521739130435%;/*15px*/}​
```

And jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XkzUK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix this code, when attaching a tab body, you should also detatch the other tab if it has already been initialized.

```
if(test2) test2.detach()
```

A more generic code would be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    if(i != tabIndexToShow && tabs[i] != null) {
        tabs[i].detach()
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLMas/1/

BUT, you should seriously consider using [JQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) (for example) which does what you are trying to do.

And also, please, clean, indent and comment your code before posting here (or better, all the time ;=)

Comment: Thanks, that sort of works but not for the initial clicks. You'll notice both tabs are present on the first click but go away after successive clicks: http://jsfiddle.net/XkzUK/1/. Also, jQuery UI tabs uses detach()? In other words, will jQuery UI tabs reload the content from the database? That is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: JQuery Ui tabs uses display = none to hide tabs, which is fine. It doen't recreate the tab each time. You have a lot of options, just browser the demo. As for the initialization, i updated my answer and your fiddle

Comment: Thanks, that works great. If I wanted to add 2 more tabs, how could I mange that with your revised code? Such as here: http://jsfiddle.net/XkzUK/3/

Comment: It seems to work. However, if you choose not you use JQuery UI Tabs, you should seriously think about a way to reuse your code rather than copy / pasting the same lines over and over. For instance you could think about an array of tabs, and loops over the elements of this array... but this would be a bit like rewriting jQuery UI tabs

Comment: Right, that's partially what I'm asking. I'd like to turn this into a function but I'm wondering how I could accomodate more tabs with your revised code? `if(test2) test2.detach();`, etc? If you click around in Fiddle v3, the tabs fall apart because I'm uncertain how to take into account the additional tabs?

Comment: Sorry, could you check out this Fiddle? I'm having trouble getting it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/XkzUK/4/